# Setting up a simple DHCP Server

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I need to setup a DHCP server on a Ubuntu virtual server. I have installed and configured isc-dhcp-server on my main server. However, I don't know where to go next. I don't know what I need to do with regards to the network interfaces for my main server (which will act as a gateway for other Host-Only servers). 
Does anyone know of a good walkthrough for beginners?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are using virtualbox. You will need to set the network settings for each of your guests to bridge mode. This should place the VM's on the network to find DHCP. See this page with explanations of networking in VirtualBox.

[VBox Networking](https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/networking_in_virtualbox1)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did figure things out. I setup a DHCP server on one my virtual machines and had all my other virtual machines run on "Host Only" or "Internal Network" mode. All my virtual machines are using the DHCP server as Gateway in order to connect to the internet.